2 divs side-by-side with a dynamic height with 2 separate absolute positioned divs in the left corners
This is what I'm trying to achieve:

I want the 2 boxes to be a dynamic height so that if the text of one is longer than the other, both boxes scale to stay the same height (for this I've used flex). The problem that I'm facing is that the "tags" which are individual DIVs with absolute positioning are both overlapping in the upper left corner of the first box:

I've tried creating 2 separate "tag" DIVs one for the left tag (with left: 3%;) and one for the right tag (with right: 53%;) buuuut, when they stack on mobile (the container is set to display: block;)
The HTML:
<div class="portfolio-container">
  
  <!-- PORTFOLIO ITEM 1 -->
  <div class="portfolio-item">
    <!-- image -->
    <div class="portfolio-image">
      <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/6728af40ad9e64292cf1c659/t/6728cafa4813c539e086174c/1730726650297/placeholder-image.jpg">
    </div>
    <!-- type -->
    <div class="portfolio-tagL">
    <div class="type-textL">Switcher</div>
    <div class="type-iconL">
    <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/6728af40ad9e64292cf1c659/t/6728cdc70f230a6d50ea5159/1730727367141/Switcher.png">
    <span class="portfolio-tagL-pop">TESTING</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- logo -->
    <div class="portfolio-logo">
    <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/6728af40ad9e64292cf1c659/t/6728c7a3f114e173907bb4d4/1730725795734/placeholder-logo.png">
    </div>
    <!-- text -->
    <div class="portfolio-text">
      One sentence description about the business and what makes them unique.
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- PORTFOLIO ITEM 2 -->
  <div class="portfolio-item">
    <!-- image -->
    <div class="portfolio-image">
      <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/6728af40ad9e64292cf1c659/t/6728cafa4813c539e086174c/1730726650297/placeholder-image.jpg">
    </div>
    <!-- type -->
    <div class="portfolio-tagR">
    <div class="type-textR">Switcher</div>
    <div class="type-iconR">
    <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/6728af40ad9e64292cf1c659/t/6728cdc70f230a6d50ea5159/1730727367141/Switcher.png">
    <span class="portfolio-tagR-pop">TESTING</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- logo -->
    <div class="portfolio-logo">
    <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/6728af40ad9e64292cf1c659/t/6728c7a3f114e173907bb4d4/1730725795734/placeholder-logo.png">
    </div>
    <!-- text -->
    <div class="portfolio-text">
      One sentence description about the business and what makes them unique.
    </div>
  </div>
    
</div>

The CSS:
.portfolio-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #fff;
  @media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    display: block;
  }
}

.portfolio-item {
  background: var(--peach);
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  @media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.portfolio-logo {
  max-width: 150px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.portfolio-text {
  line-height: 1.3em;
  font-size: .6em;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.portfolio-tagL {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 3%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 130px;
  font-size: .5em;
  font-weight: 300;
  background: var(--lilac1);
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.portfolio-tagL .portfolio-tagL-pop {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50px;
  left: 2%;
}

.portfolio-tagL:hover .portfolio-tagL-pop {
  visibility: visible;
}

.type-textL {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.type-iconL {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.portfolio-tagR .portfolio-tagR-pop {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50px;
  left: 2%;
}

.portfolio-tagR:hover .portfolio-tagR-pop {
  visibility: visible;
}

.type-textR {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.type-iconR {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've since tweaked the CSS to work as intended on desktop. So my issue now is how to get the tag positions in place on mobile where the container changes from 'flex' to 'block' and the 2 boxes are stacked instead of side-by-side.

portfolio-item needs position: relative

You are a legend, thank you \m/
